# Select datatable with join return 0

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have one `DataTable` that executes this SQL query on my MS Access database in C#:

```
DataTable dtCdDvd = cls.Fun_RetornaDataTable("SELECT tblCdDvd.Cod, tblCdDvd.Nome, tblCdDvd.Tamanho, tblTipo.Tipo, tblCdDvd.Grupo FROM [tblCdDvd] INNER JOIN [tblTipo] ON tblCdDvd.Tipo=tblTipo.Cod WHERE Status = TRUE");
```

If I use

```
DataRow[] result = dtCdDvd.Select("[Grupo]=0");
```

the result is 0 rows and exist registry with informed code.

The more interesting is if my SQL query runs

```
DataTable dtCdDvd = cls.Fun_RetornaDataTable("SELECT Grupo FROM tblCdDvd");
```

without join table my result is different of 0.

My function of return datatable

```
public DataTable Fun_RetornaDataTable(string query)
{
            DataTable dt = null;

            using (var dbcon = new OleDbConnection(Fun_ConnString()))
            {
                dbcon.Open();

                if (dbcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    var command = new OleDbCommand(query, dbcon);
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }

            return dt;
}
```

Comment: what does `Fun_RetornaDataTable` do?

Comment: this is my function with return datatable

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to understand the question, but a couple of things that stand out.

" WHERE Status = TRUE"
What is 'Status'? Is it defined in one of the tables uniquely?

When you run "SELECT Grupo FROM tblCdDvd", are you getting any rows returned?

"the result is 0 rows and exist registry with informed code"
What does this mean in English?